# I am unable to render new entries on the browser (demo version)

Tags: 404

I just started using craft and am still exploring the Happy Lager demo version. I can create new sections, fields and entries. However, when I try to render the entry on my browser by clicking on the globe icon, the URL takes me to "Page not found" error.

Am I not allowed to create new entries on the demo? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I went with the default template file which did not exist, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for following up with an answer, @user4709! Go ahead and accept it if you'd like!